# OpenGL Scaling/Translation coordinate system or order of statement error

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I rewrote the OpenGL `glTranslatef`, `glScalef`, and `glRotatef` functions. I am using these functions to draw and transform a circle and compare to the built-in functions. All seems to be in working order, and my functions work exactly as the built-in ones do, with one small exception.

When I scale with the built-in function, I move the object back to the origin, like so:

```
glTranslatef(50, 50, 0);
glScalef(2.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glTranslatef(-50, -50, 0);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, numVertices)
```

But when using my own function, I find I have to switch the translation statements to achieve the same result as above:

```
MyTranslate(-50, -50, 0);
MyScale(2.0, 1.0, 0.0);
MyTranslate(50, 50, 0);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, numVertices)
```

That is, either the coordinate system gets messed up (unlikely) or the statements are being read in a different order (more likely).

The translate function isn't anything special:

```
GLfloat translate[16] = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, x, y, z, 1 };
GLfloat modelview[16] = { 0 };
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
matrixMultiply(modelview, translate);
glLoadMatrixf(result);
```

I am confident that the scale and matrix multiplication functions are fine. Can anyone give some advice or explanation to the statement-switching phenomenon I am experiencing?

Comment: If you voted down the post, can you explain why and what I can do to fix my question?

Comment: maybe your multiplication order is wrong? For matrizes A*B != B*A

Comment: I am fairly certain I have that right. For all my transformations, I multiply the matrix as (current position) * (transformation to apply).

Comment: I'm not absolutly shure about the fixed function pipeline, but when working with shaders, OpenGL uses (transformation) * position

Comment: You are absolutely right, however, the problem ended up being the order of my statements when not working with the built-in OpenGL functions. Thanks for your expertise anyways! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize if the question was not clear or if it was constructed poorly. However, I found a solution and would like to share it with the StackOverflow community.

The problem was very simple: In OpenGL, the order of built-in functions is "reversed" such that the **transformation closest to the draw object statement is applied first**. When writing and using my own functions, which simply manipulate the Modelview Matrix, I had to "reverse" (that is, put in the correct order) the transformations, so that **the transformation which appeared first chronologically in code is applied first**.

Example with OpenGL built-in functions:

```
glTranslatef(30, 30, 0);   // Translate / perform other transformations
glTranslatef(50, 50, 0);   // Translate back to original position
glRotatef(20, 0, 0, 1);    // Rotate object
glScalef(1.5, 2.5, 1.0);   // Scale object
glTranslatef(-50, -50, 0); // Translate object to the origin
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, numVertices); // Draw the object
```

The order is critical here. But when using my functions, the order had to be reverse (put in "logical order") to apply changes to the Modelview Matrix correctly. Anyone with a basic understanding of transformation matrices knows that multiplying matrices in the wrong order will produce an entirely different result than desired.

Example with self-written functions:

```
MyTranslate(-50, -50, 0); // Translate object to the origin
MyScale(1.5, 2.5, 1.0);   // Scale object
MyRotate(20, 0, 0, 1);    // Rotate object
MyTranslate(50, 50, 0);   // Translate back to original position
MyTranslate(30, 30, 0);   // Translate / perform other transformations
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, numVertices); // Draw the object
```